# Why, after assembling the .apk file, some functions that work on the local server ( EXPO) do not work in it?

Tags: react-native, expo, apk

I am developing a React Native mobile application using Expo.  The application has a filtering function for certain parameters. When I launch the app via Expo on my device, everything works correctly. However, after building the .apk (I use eas-cli for this purpose) and opening the application on the same (my) device, the filtering function stops working (no errors occur).
[how it looks on the Expo server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoGtv.png);

[how it looks in .apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9ZQg.jpg);
[how it looks in .apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOWtO.jpg);

I don't have any thoughts at all about why this might happen, because everything works correctly on the Expo server.

This is my build file:

```
{
  "build": {
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease",
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

the command I use to build:

```
eas build -p android --profile preview2
```

Comment: You might have some optimizations happening in the build process that remove parts of the code the compiler thinks aren't getting used. Or things are getting renamed to save space.
Try turning off speed and space saving options, try building in "Debug" mode, and see if that helps?

Comment: your question lack of informations, what is your package? what lib you use for that filter, and there's no code to produce